# Neutral axis of T shaped beam?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

I am not a mechanics or physics student but a computer science student. I came across a question related to find [neutral axis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutral_axis) of figure but I do not have slightest idea of what it is and how to find it.

Can someone please tell what would be neutral axis and how is it calculated for following T shaped beam?

[image: For following T beam]

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutral_axis. Googling for "neutral axis of T beam" will find lots of pages telling you how to calculate the position of the neutral axis.

Comment: I couldnot find anything that is why i asked here :)

Answer (score 1):

The formula for the neutral axis of a curved member is $$r_n = \frac{\int \,  \rm{d} A}{\int \frac{1}{r} \rm{d} A} $$ but it is much simpler to handle the straight beam case.

If your *T* section has widths from the bottom up $w_1 = 3$, $w_2 =1$ and heights $h_1=1$, $h_2=3$ then the neutral axis is located from the bottom surface at a height of

$$ y_n = \frac{w_1 h_1 \frac{h_1}{2} + w_2 h_2 \left( h_1 + \frac{h_2}{2} \right)}{w_1 h_1 + w_2 h_2 }= 1.50\;{\rm in} $$